# What is the definition of "periodicity of the data"?

Tags: time-series

I'm reading a research paper where it says. **Here $m$ is the periodicity of the data (e.g., 12 for monthly series).**

I understand:

- There are twelve months in a year. So I suspect periodicity relates to the max value of the period before it resets.

Questions:

- What is the exact definition of periodically of data?
- How do you calculate it?
- What would the periodicity of a yearly series be?

Comment: I wouldn't think that this was a universally defined notion.  Context ought to make it clear what is intended.  Here it would seem to suggest that the authors want to retain to, say, look at the January data only.  Easy to imagine a situation in which that would be a good idea.

Comment: Check out :: [[A]] "Periodicity Detection in Time Series Databases" https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ake/pub/Tkde-0129-0504-1.pdf [[B]] "Periodicity Detection in Time Series Databases" https://www.stat.colostate.edu/~piotr/perAS.pdf [[C]] "A Survey on Periodicity Detection Techniques in Time Series Databases" https://www.ijert.org/research/a-survey-on-periodicity-detection-techniques-in-time-series-databases-IJERTV2IS121040.pdf :: It might get you on the track to know more.